# making discord bots online 24/7 in visual studio code discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot that I want to make online 24/7 in visual studio code and need help. Like is there a different way than Heroku and mongo DB?

Comment: You can host your bot on any "machine", for example you could use a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @Paul i dont have a machine like raspberry i can use mongo db if its the only choice

Comment: `visual studio code` is only IDE (editor with extra extensions), and we use IDE only to develop code. When code is ready then we don't need IDE. You run it directly in system's console/terminal as `python script.py` And to run it online you need to put code on some computer which can work 24/7 and it has access to internet and run `python script.py`, You can use servers like `Heroku` or you can use your local computer - but it would have to run 24/7 with access to internet.

Comment: In order for a bot to be online 24/7 you need to have the server it’s being hosted on always online. Usually you will have to pay for this if you don’t want to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create an account on https://replit.com!
The create a repl, upload your code there.
Then, you can follow the istructions here: https://www.codementor.io/@garethdwyer/building-a-discord-bot-with-python-and-repl-it-miblcwejz#keeping-our-bot-alive to learn how to keep your bot alive by just creating a single file.
Follow instructions, press "Run" on replit and it's done!